# Do all wireless clients need to support OFDMA for it to work?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router

[OFDMA](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/wireless/what-is-ofdma.html) (orthogonal frequency-division multiple access) allows for simultaneous communication between the router and multiple wireless client.

But do *all* clients in 5Ghz band need to support OFDMA for it to actually work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't need all clients to support it. If just one client of an AP, plus the AP itself, support it, it could theoretically be used for simultaneous bidirectional transmission.

Given typical client traffic patterns, you probably won't see it get used much until two heavy-use clients (plus the AP of course) support it, so that the AP can use it to transmit to both clients at the exact same time.

Comment: Why 2? Isn't it enough for Router and 1 client (say Laptop) to support it?

Comment: @Slav Good point. I've tweaked my answer.